# Port mapping in Docker on Mac OSX installed with Docker Toolbox

Tags: macos, networking, nginx, docker, docker-toolbox

I installed Docker on a Mac using the Docker Toolbox.

I opened Docker Quickstart Terminal and ran

```
docker run hello-world
```

That works fine.

Then I tried:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:80 nginx
```

I can see that the container is added. `docker log` with the container id returns nothing but I think that's normal?

When I browse to `localhost:8080` with chrome I don't see the nginx welcome page. I've tried running a few different containers that are supposed to serve traffic but none of them have worked. The existing github issues and SO questions all seem to be talking about things which don't exist anymore - or at least are not default on Mac OSX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localhost` is not the host where your docker is running.  You need to go to the IP address of your running docker daemon.

To find the IP address for your docker machine, run the command:

```
docker-machine ip default
```

where `default` is the name of your VM (as is the case I think for most installations).

If that command returned something like `192.168.99.100`, then you can reach your running docker container and it's exposed port like this: `192.168.99.100:8080`.

Comment: It didn't work for me, could you have a look here please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36551466/access-docker-forwarded-port-on-mac