# Access Docker forwarded port on Mac

Tags: macos, docker, port, forwarding

There is a related post here: [Port mapping in Docker on Mac OSX installed with Docker Toolbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35496273/port-mapping-in-docker-on-mac-osx-installed-with-docker-toolbox)

but it didn't work for me

**Get ports for container**

docker port 485186e65a5e

```
8080/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:33360
8088/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:33359
19888/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:33358
50070/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:33357
50075/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:33356
8042/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:33361
```

**Check that someone listens to ports in container**

```
bash-4.1# netstat -alnpt | grep 19888
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:19888             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1094/java
```

**Do wget in container**

```
bash-4.1# wget 127.0.0.1:19888
--2016-04-11 14:16:54--  http://127.0.0.1:19888/
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:19888... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://127.0.0.1:19888/jobhistory [following]
--2016-04-11 14:16:54--  http://127.0.0.1:19888/jobhistory
Reusing existing connection to 127.0.0.1:19888.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 6763 (6.6K) [text/html]
Saving to: `index.html'

100%[================================================================================================================================================================================>] 6,763       --.-K/s   in 0s      

2016-04-11 14:16:54 (182 MB/s) - `index.html' saved [6763/6763]
```

**Try to access forwarded port from host, no luck... :(((**

```
$docker-machine ip default
192.168.99.100
$ wget 192.168.99.100:33358
--2016-04-11 16:18:04--  http://192.168.99.100:33358/
Connecting to 192.168.99.100:33358... failed: Connection refused.
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 10):

Omg, desired service started on **127.0.0.1** in container, that is why it wasn't visible from outside world. I've modified service config to start on 0.0.0.0 and now I can access forwarded container port

Comment: How did you configure the container to start with 0.0.0.0 ?

Comment: I was talking about my web service running inside the container. That server started on 127.0.0.1 so want not visible outside the container.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and was able to fix it by specifying the host that the server within the container uses.

*NOTE: when using **host** below, it means a web server host. When I use **host-machine**, I mean the main operating system I'm using, (i.e. not a container or a web server, just my laptop as a machine)*

**The Problem**

Running web servers on the container like `webpack-dev-server` and `http-server` automatically run the app using a host of `http://localhost`. Typically you will see that in the output when you start the server. Something like :

`Project is running at http://localhost:8080`

or

`Server available at http://127.0.0.1:8080`

On most machines, `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` are the same thing. This host is **not publicly viewable**. As a result, your host machine can't see anything, even though it's looking in the right place.

**Solution**

You should specify a public host when you run the server inside your container.

`webpack-dev-server --port 8080 --host 0.0.0.0`

or

`http-server -p 8080 -a 0.0.0.0`

Because the `0.0.0.0` address is viewable to any outside machine, you should be able to see your app working as expected from your host machine.

*NOTE: This works for any server, like Python's SimpleHTTPServer, etc. Just look up how to change the host for your chosen server in the documentation*

**Resources/Nods**
(how to run webpack-dev-erver with a publicly accessible host)[[How to make the webpack dev server run on port 80 and on 0.0.0.0 to make it publicly accessible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33272967/how-to-make-the-webpack-dev-server-run-on-port-80-and-on-0-0-0-0-to-make-it-publ])

Comment: Ahh!  Thank you for this!

I was struggling to connect to mongodb running inside docker. The container was running, I saw the port mapping `localhost:9000 -> 27017/tcp`. I could connect to mongodb via `localhost:27017` from inside the container, but trying to connect to it from outside did not work.

Starting mongodb w/ this option: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/reference/program/mongod/#std-option-mongod.--bind_ip

```
CMD mongod ---bind_ip 0.0.0.0
```

Fixed it!